# Why is Python regex slower 5 times on aws instance than my local mac OS X with similar specs?

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services

I have the following regex code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import re

start_time = time.time()

input_string = """သီဟိုဠ်မှ ဉာဏ်ကြီးရှင်သည် အာယုဝဍ်ဎနဆေးညွှန်းစာကို ဇလွန်ဈေးဘေးဗာဒံပင်ထက် အဓိဋ္ဌာန်လျက် ဂဃနဏဖတ်ခဲ့သည်။"""

if type(input_string) is not unicode:
    input_string = unicode(input_string, "utf8")

input_string = re.sub(ur"([\u1000-\u104F])\s+(?=[\u1000-\u104F])", r"\1", input_string)

input_string = re.sub(ur"\u103A\u1037", u"\u1037\u103A", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"\u1036\u102F", u"\u102F\u1036", input_string)

input_string = re.sub(ur"[\u200B\u200C]", "", input_string)

input_string = re.sub(ur"([\u102D\u102E])\u1030", ur"\1\u102F", input_string)

input_string = re.sub(ur"(\u1047)(?=[\u1000-\u101C\u101E-\u102A\u102C\u102E-\u103F\u104C-\u109F\u0020])", u"\u101B", input_string)
input_string = re.sub(ur"\u1031\u1047", u"\u1031\u101B", input_string)

print "time taken -> %s" % (time.time() - start_time)
```

### Benchmarks

my local Mac (3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 with 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3 and Fusion Drive)

aws instance (m4.xlarge, ebs_optimized)

local ubuntu (2 cores, 8GB RAM)

digital ocean (1 core, 512MB RAM)

### Time Taken

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|      OS       |       TIME        |
+---------------+-------------------+
| Mac           | 0.00268292427063  |
| AWS           |  0.0100150108337  |
| Local Ubuntu  | 0.00330495834351  |
| Digital Ocean |  0.00202393531799 |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, AWS is taking ~ 5 times longer than my other machines.

I'm using `python2.7`. Can you please explain to me what is wrong? Is aws instance that bad? How can I check what is wrong with my m4.xlarge?

*Thanks*

Comment: What [*kind* of AWS instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) did you use. A storage-optimised instance won't win CPU performance benchmarks.

Comment: This is more an optimisation question than a programming question, isn't it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm using m4.xlarge which has 4 vCPU and 16GB RAM. Would c4.xlarge (4 vCPU and 7.5GB RAM) be better than m4.xlarge for CPU performance?

Comment: @moeseth: tbh I don't know; I have little experience with AWS computing power. You'd have to try it out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I tried with c4. It is way faster. Will need explanation from some aws experts. -.-

Comment: @moeseth: `c` family instances are design for high computation workload and hence your code will execute faster. Where as`m` family instances are memory efficient and designed to efficiently store memories in the database. Choice of AWS machine is totally dependent on your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that I was using python 2.7.3 on my aws instance. After I updated to 2.7.10, it is now as fast as my other machines.

Cheers.